# Count characters from a Multiline Textbox

Tags: vb.net

I want to play a little with the Textbox. How do I count the items of a textbox?

Example: The first line contains the characters: `2 4 6 8`,
so there are 4 characters. How do I display this count in another textbox?

Comment: You need to put some code to help us understand your question and give you an answer...

Comment: please check : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do, Is to remove spaces and count the length and pass to second textbox

Try this:

```
 secondTextBox.Text = firstTextBox.Text.Where(Function(x) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).Count()
        End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: He did not make a difference, if we have 12 - 16 - 18, 6 characters will be displayed, and he does not take it as a integer. because in fact there should be only 3 numbers separated by space or comma.

Comment: One small point: rather than using `Where(…).Count()` you can use `Count(…)`.

Comment: So you want to count number of integers not characters? @MarioSandu

Comment: Yes, sorry for that :) but even so, that's what I want to help. but I need both of them. both will help me, so that's good with counting the characters.

Comment: @MarioSandu, maybe if you were to provide a PROPER explanation of the problem in the question, people wouldn't have to guess at what you want and end up guessing the wrong thing. You said "characters" in your question and now you imply that that's not what you meant. Ask the question you actually want answered. Provide multiple examples if doing so helps to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help,

```
var nonSpaceCharCount = inputText.Count(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c));
var letterOrDigitCount = inputText.Count(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));
```